# Sum of the first 5 even numbers from the array

Tags: c++, arrays, sum

So, I need to get the sum of the first 5 even numbers from my array, this is the code that I've got so far, have no clue what to do next. It runs, but the result is incorrect

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int niz[10];
cout << "Unesi 10 brojeva:";
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    cin >> niz[i];
}

int suma = 0;
int parni[5];
int j = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if (niz[i] % 2 == 0) {
        niz[i] == parni[j];
        j++;
        if (j == 5) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    suma = parni[i] + suma;
}
cout << suma;
system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `niz[i] == parni[j];`   `==` is a compare operator, not an assign operator.  Use `=`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
niz[i] == parni[j];
```

does nothing. (It tests if `niz[i]` happens to be equal to the current, uninitialized value of `parni[j]`, and throws away the result of the comparison.)

You want to store `niz[i]` in `parni[j]`, so do this:

```
parni[j] = niz[i];
```

Incidentally, there is a problem if there are fewer than 5 even numbers in the `niz` array. In that case, you still sum up all five entries of the `parni` array, using uninitialized values, which is Bad. One way to avoid this is to just sum up the even entries as you find them, without using a secondary array.
IE, do `suma += niz[i]` at the line in question, and get rid of `parni` altogether.

Comment: If your compiler didn't warn you that this line had no effect, you either need to get a better compiler or learn how to get your compiler to issue warnings.

Comment: We've got a close reason for such issues. Instead of writing an answer, leave a comment and flag as off-topic for _a simple or typographical error_. Otherwise the deletion process for that question is just slowed down.

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake, I accidentally put == between, thanks. It now works.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're really required to use arrays here, `vector`s will work much more nicely.

You can also use a couple of standard algorithms to make your life easier (especially `std::copy_if` and `std::accumulate`).

```
// for the moment I'll ignore the code to read the input from the user:
auto input = read_input();

auto pos = std::remove_if(input.begin(), input.end(), 
                          [](int i) { return i % 2 != 0; });

// assume that `input` always contains at least 5 elements
pos = std::min(pos, input.begin() + 5);

sum = std::accumulate(input.begin(), pos, 0);
```